# Формат вывода промиса на консоль

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, promise, google-chrome-devtools

При выводе промиса на консоль он показывается примерно так:

```
˅ Promise {<fulfilled>: 42}
    ˃ __proto__: Promise
    [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
    [[PromiseResult]]: 42
```

Эти `[[PromiseState]]` и `[[PromiseResult]]` показываются на уровне объекта, а не прототипа, однако:

- они не являются его свойствами
- они не являются символами (там при выводе нельзя избавиться от слова Symbol)
- они не являются приватными полями (при выводе нет решётки)
- они в отличие от всего перечисленного показываются после `__proto__`, а не до

[image: скриншот]

Я понимаю, что это некие внутренние поля, принадлежащие инстансу промиса, но тем не менее мне интересно, как же они реализованы и почему это вызывает столь необычное отображение? А ещё, возможно ли создать свой собственный объект, который будет выводиться аналогичным образом?

Comment: Низя) Это т.н. [internal slots](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots)  [Promise](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-executor), публичный API для них не предоставляется)

Comment: @vp_arth 1. Ответы - в ответы. 2. Слотов у него больше, но показываются только эти два. И у объектов пачка слотов есть, правда, они все с функциями.

Answer (score 1):

Некоторые встроенные методы, написаны не на javascript, поэтому могут выглядеть необычно, или вы вообще не сможете посмотреть реализацию в консоли. И конечно, можно написать свою реализацию promise, это есть во многих туториалах по javascript.

Comment: Так я не реализацию ищу.